# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.4.0

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I m trying to compile a **open source project (downloaded from github)**,

[build.gradle (Module app) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLU2P.png)

i also attached my **SDK Manager Image**,

[SDK Manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHyF0.png)

i google to much for this problem but due to (Im) **new android bee** i cant understand problems and solution of these problem properly. I **install API level 23** for solution but nothing gained. any help will be appropriated, thanks in advance.

**Android studio information**:

Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 2, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

*********** My build.gradle (Project: XXX)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi2zL.png)

Comment: in your build.gradle (project module) add  google()  in repositries

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer with any text, image or reference?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `google()` to build.gradle(Project:xxx)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // ---------------------------------(here)
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
} 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  //-----------------------------(here)
        jcenter()
        maven {
                 url 'https://maven.google.com'
             }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```